# How to make a class that implements IRunnable more generic?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have the following class:

```
private class MyRunnable : Java.Lang.Object, Java.Lang.IRunnable
{
    private MainActivity mainActivity;

    public MyRunnable(MainActivity mainActivity)
    {
        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    }

    public void Run()
    {

        mainActivity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
            mainActivity.ShowAlert();
        });

    }
}
```

Then I start it in OnCreate method like that:

```
MyRunnable myRunnable = new MyRunnable(this);
Java.Lang.Thread thread = new Java.Lang.Thread(myRunnable);
thread.Start();
```

But the class is too tied up with `MainActivity` and `ShowAlert` method. If I want to work with another activity and another method for example:

```
private class MyRunnable : Java.Lang.Object, Java.Lang.IRunnable
{
    private (SomeActivity) someActivity;

    public MyRunnable((SomeActivity) someActivity)
    {
        this.someActivity = someActivity;
    }

public void Run()
{

    someActivity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
    {
        mainActivity.(SomeOtherMethod)();
    });

}
```

}

I wouldn't be able to. Is there any way to make it more generic? (I'm using Xamarin.Android)

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. Can you show some pseudo-code or some example of what you mean by more generic?

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 3):

A simple way is to create an Action-based runnable, passing the Action as a parameter to the runnable .actr (you can also pass additional params, etc...)

#### C# Action in Java Runnable

```
public class MyRunnable : Java.Lang.Object, Java.Lang.IRunnable
{
    readonly WeakReference<Action> actionRef;

    public MyRunnable(Action action)
    {
        actionRef = new WeakReference<Action>(action);
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        actionRef.TryGetTarget(out Action action);
        action?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

#### Usage:

```
var runnable = new MyRunnable(async () =>
{
    // Do whatever you need to do, including capturing of local vars, app/activity context, etc.
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Toast.MakeText(this, "In runnable", ToastLength.Long).Show();
    ~~~
});
runnable.Run();
```

Comment: I follow this approach as well seems easy to understand and logical at the same time

Comment: Hi, @Sushi, I have a question, how to call MainActivity's method with the Usage code if now I am in other Activities.

Comment: @JoeLv Not sure what you mean by "Usage code"... but other Activities accept the current one are *never* guaranteed to still be instanced and unless the method you are calling is static you can not it and at that point you might as well move that method to a generic static helper class.

Comment: can we use thread.run method without using runnable? will this be the same?

Comment: @batmaci `Runnable` is Java/Android specific and some APIs require a Runnable, otherwise using a .Net Thread (or a Task and thus a thread from the threadpool) will work just fine (but that is without knowing your use-case of course)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it would be easy to implement an interface-based approach:

```
public interface IRunnableActivity
{
    void Run();
}

public class MainActivity : Activity, IRunnableActivity
{
    ...

    public void Run()
    {
        ShowAlert();
    }
}

public class SomeOtherActivity : Activity, IRunnableActivity
{
    ...

    public void Run()
    {
        SomeOtherMethod();
    }
}

private class MyRunnable : Java.Lang.Object, Java.Lang.IRunnable
{
    private IRunnableActivity activity;

    public MyRunnable(IRunnableActivity runnableActivity)
    {
        activity = runnableActivity;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        runnableActivity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
            runnableActivity.Run();
        });
    }
}
```

I'll leave you the exercise of deciding how best to get `RunOnUiThread` with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decouple `ShowAler` from `MainActivity`, create a `Utils` class, and add the method:

```
class Utils
{
    public static void ShowAlert()
    {
        Android.Util.Log.Error("lv", "=======");
    }
}
```

In your `MyRunnable` class, use the base class `Activity` to achieve polymorphism

```
public class MyRunnable : Java.Lang.Object, Java.Lang.IRunnable
{
    Activity mActivity;

    public MyRunnable(Activity activity)
    {
        mActivity = activity;

    }

    public void Run()
    {
        mActivity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
            Utils.ShowAlert();

        }
       );
    }
}
```

And then you can use the under code in any Activities:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new MyRunnable(this));
thread.Start();
```